# Exercise $10.6$ - Francesco Maggi's book

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, tangent-spaces

$\textbf{Exercise}$: if $\mu:{\mathbb R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb R$ is a Lipschitz function, and we define $f:{\mathbb R}^{n-1} \to {\mathbb R}^{n}$ as $f(z)=(z,\mu(z))$,  $z \in {\mathbb R}^{n-1}$, then $\Gamma= f({\mathbb R}^{n-1})$ is locally $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$-rectifiable and, for a.e.$z \in {\mathbb R}^{n-1}$,

\begin{align*}
T_{f(z)}\Gamma =& v(z)^{\bot}      &       v(z)&=(-\nabla'\mu(z),1)
\end{align*}

$\textbf{lemma 10.4}$ : If $M= f(E)$ is a $k$-dimensional regular Lipschitz image in ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ and $z \in E $ then,
\begin{align*}
T_{x}M&= \nabla f(z)({\mathbb R}^{k})     &       x&=f(z)
\end{align*}

I can use of the lemma 10.4 above then $T_{f(z)}\Gamma= \nabla f(z)({\mathbb R}^{n-1}) $, how to prove that $\forall y \in \nabla f(z)({\mathbb R}^{k})$ $$ y \cdot  v(z) = 0  $$ here I used the  F. Maggi's book, and it is very difficult for me to carry out this exercise. If someone could help me, at least with an idea, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What does regular in 10.4 means?

Comment: It refers more to $f(E)$ a regular lipschitz image that means that $f$ is $1-1$ differential in $E$, $ \forall x \in E$ , it is a point of density $1$, and it is a lebesgue point for$D_f$.